# JQuery Mobile "tap" event on button also triggers "tap" on element behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile page in which the content is a list in which the user can tap to select (highlight) elements.  After a desired number of list elements are selected, they can be deleted by tapping the Delete button in the footer.  The page works fine on my desktop, but in a mobile environment (iPhone & iPad), pressing the delete button also triggers a tap event for the list element *underneath* the button.

This picture shows how my page normally looks.  If the user taps the delete button, the selected element is deleted but the element underneath the delete button will be highlighted.

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

EDIT (some code):
Here is the event mapper:

```
$(document).delegate("#delete-button", "tap", deleteButtonTapped);
```

Here is the function:

```
var deleteButtonTapped = function(event, data) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var possessedNotes = [];

    $('.ui-btn-up-e').each(function(){

        $(this).slideUp();
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split(" "); //id is loanId + " " + docId
        possessedNotes.push(notesList[[id[1], id[2]]]);
    });

//  console.log(possessedNotes);

    $.post("srv/move_notes_into_possession.php", { possessedNotes: possessedNotes }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, "json");

    $("#footer").slideUp();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm maintaining an old app that uses this feature, and I'm seeing the exact same issue happening.

I was able to prevent underlying elements from also being 'tapped' using the event method, `preventDefault`.

```
$('#cancelButton').on('tap', function(event) {
            
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // event-handler code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Events on DOM elements propagate or "bubble". You need to use jQuery's `event.stopPropagation()` function in the event handler to stop the event from traveling to the parent elements.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Thanks for the info! But, this didn't fix my problem. I don't think the delete button element and the list element are related DOM elements. Another question, should I be using event.stopPropagation() whenever I map an event to a function?

Comment: When you say "this didn't fix my problem" it could be that you're not doing it right - post some code. If the delete button is on top of another element, the event will pass through to the elements underneath. No, you don't necessarily want to stop propagation in every case.

Comment: Does adding `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` after `event.stopPropagation()` make any difference?

Comment: Nope seems to be the same.

Comment: I found the source of the problem.  When footer.slideUp() is called, the element underneath is revealed and tapped in the same motion.  Would you know how I could approach sliding the footer back but not triggering the tap event on the element underneath? Thanks so much